# How to show $N_G(Z(G))\ge G?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $C_G(Z(G))=G$ then   show that $N_{G}(Z(G))=G$

My attempt :  $N_G(Z(G))$ always contains  $C_G(Z(G)) \implies  N_G(Z(G))\le G$

**My confusion** :  How to show  $N_G(Z(G))\ge G?$

**Note** :$Z(G)$  denote the centre of $ G$

$N_G$ denote the noremalizer and $C_G$ denote the centralizer

Comment: Just use the definition of normaliser and centre.  And you have the inclusion between centraliser and normaliser the wrong way.

Comment: I would recommend to include the definitions for $C_G$, $N_G$, and Z(G) . So, people can follow and they can give their comments.

Comment: The normaliser is contained in $G$ *by definition*. That is, the bit you have "shown" is obvious (and you should try and see why it is obvious).